# How to retrieve Lotus Notes attachments?

Tags: types, lotus-notes, attachment, lotusscript, type-mismatch

I’m trying to export all of the documents and their attachments from a Lotus Notes database (with Designer 7.0).  I can get the document data and can get an attachment, but only if I hard code the name.  The two methods, in LotusScript, I’ve found for getting the filename programmatically aren’t working, as shown in the lower two code blocks.  In the first, doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" ) returns Nothing, and in the second, there’s a Type Mismatch during execution on the Forall line.
Any help on how to extract the attachments would be greatly appreciated!  I’m not sure whether the attachments are stored as “attachments” or OLE, but I suspect as attachments, since they’re primarily PDFs.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)  
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim query As String
Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim fileCount As Integer
Dim attachment As NotesEmbeddedObject 
Dim fileName As String

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
' get a document that has an attachment
Set collection = db.FTSearch( "06/25/2013", 10 )

fileNum% = Freefile()
fileName$ = "c:\kcw\lotusexport.txt"
Open fileName$ For Output As fileNum%
Write #fileNum%, "docs found", collection.Count

Set doc = collection.GetFirstDocument
' write out document properties
Forall x In doc.Items
    Write #fileNum%, x.Name, " = ",  x.Text
End Forall
'extract document (using hardcoded name)
Set attachment = doc.GetAttachment("OCSE-FRONT_SCANTODESKTOP_06262013-104822.pdf")
Call attachment.ExtractFile _
( "c:\kcw\attachment" )

'Try to get attachment through "Body", but rtitem is Nothing
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
Write #fileNum%, "rtitem is Nothing", rtitem Is Nothing
fileCount = 0
If Not rtitem Is Nothing Then
    If ( rtitem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
        Write #fileNum%, "rtitem is RICHTEXT"
        Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
            Write #fileNum%, "has Embedded Objects"
            fileCount = fileCount + 1
            Write #fileNum%,"rtitem num", fileCount
            Call o.ExtractFile _
            ( "c:\kcw\newfile" & Cstr(fileCount) )
        End Forall
    End If
End If

'Fails with "Type mismatch" at Forall loop
If doc.HasEmbedded Then
    Write #fileNum%, "doc has embedded"     
    Forall objects In doc.EmbeddedObjects
        Write #fileNum%, "in for loop"
        Write #fileNum%, "filename= ", object.Source
    End Forall
End If

Close fileNum%
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by Dim session..etc.?

Comment: Is Body field exist in every document? It is very odd that it returns nothing.

Comment: You definitely should look at error handling techniques in LotusScript. There can be some issue with document processed in loop - anytime. Just from top of the head: different form (no Body field), corrupted doc (.isValid), invalid filename (internal attachment name can differ from one shown in client) and so on.

Comment: @zanbri: You need to declare the NotesObjects you use. Any Notes developer would recognize those lines, you write them all the time. :-)

Answer (score 4):

that will give you list of all attachments in document

```
objects =  Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues with your code.
First of all, like others already said, you need to add error handling.
Second, use the Source property of the NotesEmbeddedObject class to get the original file name of the attachment. You have to write code yourself to handle duplicates, of course.

Here are a couple of lines in a program I have written.

```
Forall i In doc.Items
  ' *** Locate attachments and detach them
  If Left$(i.Name,1)<>"$" Or Lcase(i.Name)="$file" Then
    If i.IsSummary = False Then
      If Not Isempty(i.EmbeddedObjects) Then
        If ( i.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
          Forall obj In i.EmbeddedObjects
            If ( obj.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then
              Call obj.ExtractFile(basePath & obj.Source)  
            End If
          End Forall
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Forall
```

The program will export all documents in a database as XML, detach any attachments, export any embedded images and also link those detached/exported files to the XML files. You can find out more about it here: http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you didn't quote whcih line caused the error. Best addecrror trapping to get info on which line the error occurs :

at top of procedure (1st line?) ..

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)  
On error goto handler
```

At bottom  of sub ...

```
fin:
exit sub

handler:
msgbox "Error " & Error$ & " line " & Erl 
resume fin
```

End Sub

Helps a lot whe  diagnosing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Notes so thanks for all the input on making the code better and for solutions!  I ran a quick test with the below code and found it works on at least one document (TBD on the whole database).  I found that the filename is stored in Items, in the $FILE item. This code gets the filename then extracts the file:

```
Dim item As NotesItem
 'assumes first item is $FILE
Set item = doc.Items( 0 )
Dim attachmentName As String
attachmentName = item.Values(0)
Write #fileNum%, "attachmentName= ", attachmentName
Set attachment = doc.GetAttachment(attachmentName)
Call attachment.ExtractFile _
( "c:\kcw\" + attachmentName)
```

Comment: You can't assume $File is the first item. It won't always be true.